# Handle + keyboard  на Delphi-7

Tags: delphi-7

Здравствуйте! Как получить активное окно в `Memo1`, но так чтобы оно менялось при нажатии на клавиши.

Например, я открыл мой компьютер, нажал на любую клавишу и в `memo1` отобразился заголовок активного окна и так далее..

Comment: GetForegroundWindow + GetWindowText

Answer (score 2):

В таймере с интервалом 0.1 - 0.5(желательно в таком диапазоне) получайте хэндл актианого окна системы функцией `GetForegroundWindow`, а затем используйте полученный хэндл в функции `GetWindowText` для получения текста заголовка окна.

Правда, чтобы посмотреть, добавился ли в TMemo новый текст, надо будет активировать окно, таймер, соответственно, сработает для вашего окна.